# How to run a jar file on the usb

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have a usb app whose class file is situated on a usb.When I am creating a jar file for the app on the usb but I am not able to run the app through jarfile but while using command prompt I am able to run the app.I think the problem is with the manifest.txt(situated on the usb drive) file that I am creating,so please if anyone can help that how should I give a relative path in the manifest file as the app I am making is a usb app.

Comment: Who is the "it" from "It's not running."?

Comment: You really should read some tutorials ... and also [google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=MjHNUqGlJoOEtAbFu4GgBQ#q=java+manifest)

Answer (score 0):

It's currently inpossible to do this on your compueter since windows 7. You can run automatically the jar or exe file when the usb got plugged.

Justin